# Swapping numbers with characters inside an array

Tags: c

I have to generate a random array with 0, 1, or 2 and swap those with specific characters. E.g.: every single 1 should be displayed as 'B'. I got my random array but I have no idea how to swap out the variables inside my array. The numbers should be replaced in the print only.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 

#define N 5
#define M 5

void print_array();
char get_symbol();
           
int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    int a[M][N];
    srand(time(NULL)); // Initialisiere Zufallsgenerator
    // Weise den Elementen des Arrays Zufallszahlen zu
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) { //i-te Zeile
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) { //j-te Spalte
            a[i][j] = (rand() % 3); // Erzeuge Zufallszahl
        }
    }
    print_array(a, M, N);
}

void print_array(int a[][N], int m, int n) {
    int i, j;
    printf("Spalte : ");
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%d ", j + 1);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("Zeile %d: ", i + 1);
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
             printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// this function is only returning "B"

void print_array(int a[][N], int m, int n) {
    int i, j;
    printf("Spalte : ");
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%d ", j + 1);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("Zeile %d: ", i + 1);
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] = 0) {
                printf("A");
            }
            else if(a[i][j] = 1) {
                printf("B");
            }    
            else {
                printf("C");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: C or C#? they're different languages.

Comment: You're missing the argument type declarations in the prototype for `print_array()`.

Comment: You could use a string like `char *replacements = "ABC";`. Then you can use `replacements[a[i][j]])`

Comment: Where is your problem? You have everything you need. What exactly stops you from checking what number it is and print the belonging character in your `print_array`? Seems a bit strange to me that THIS is where you got stuck if you wrote the rest of the code yourself.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Do you want to replace `1` with `B` in the array values, so that any other function that might use the array will see the changed values or do you want replace the values while printing, so that the output shows the new value but the array keeps its old value? Do you want to store characers `'0'` ... `'2'` or numbers `0` ... `2` in the array?

Comment: Every time i'm trying to check the numbers a[i][j] is always = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using "=" instead of "==" for comparing two values in if else conditions.

```
       for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (a[i][j] = 0){
            printf("A");
        }
        else if(a[i][j] = 1){
            printf("B");
        }    
        else{
            printf("C");
        }
    }
```

You have to compare values not assign while you are doing the opposite.

```
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (a[i][j] == 0){
            printf("A");
        }
        else if(a[i][j] == 1){
            printf("B");
        }    
        else{
            printf("C");
        }
    }
```

Replace your code with above code.

Comment: Oh god thank you, i'm lookin at this for hours now.

Comment: Mark this answer as correct. So that your question can get closed now  @ZuCh

Comment: Compilers typically have options to turn on warnings which would catch stuff like that.  For example, if you're using gcc, you should always compile with `-Wall`.  I also like to throw in `-Wextra` and `-Wshadow`.